On-premise bare metal kubernetes cluster not able to manage after updating certificates
Kubernetes version: 1.22 Cloud being used: bare-metal Installation method: OnPremise Host OS: Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.10
Good morning, I currently have a problem after updating the certificates of my Kubernetes cluster with the kubeadm kubeadm certs renew all command, we have a Kubernetes cluster in On-Premise that has 2 masters and 6 worker nodes, after the update we lost management of the cluster, what was done was apply the aforementioned command and update the certificates in one of the masters and replicate the /etc/kubernetes folder with the certificates in the other, so that both masters had their certificates renewed:
Renewal Master Principal TMT102 (10.164.5.236)

Renewal of Secondary Master TCOLD013 (10.161.169.26)

However, the issue is that the apiserver pod does not start and in both masters it gives the following error:
*I0909 15:46:36.537724       1 server.go:553] external host was not specified, using 10.164.5.236*
*I0909 15:46:36.538897       1 server.go:161] Version: v1.22.0*
*I0909 15:46:37.156242       1 shared_informer.go:240] Waiting for caches to sync for node_authorizer*
*I0909 15:46:37.158840       1 plugins.go:158] Loaded 12 mutating admission controller(s) successfully in the following order: NamespaceLifecycle,LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,NodeRestriction,TaintNodesByCondition,Priority,DefaultTolerationSeconds,DefaultStorageClass,StorageObjectInUseProtection,RuntimeClass,DefaultIngressClass,MutatingAdmissionWebhook.*
*I0909 15:46:37.158879       1 plugins.go:161] Loaded 11 validating admission controller(s) successfully in the following order: LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,PodSecurity,Priority,PersistentVolumeClaimResize,RuntimeClass,CertificateApproval,CertificateSigning,CertificateSubjectRestriction,ValidatingAdmissionWebhook,ResourceQuota.*
*I0909 15:46:37.161155       1 plugins.go:158] Loaded 12 mutating admission controller(s) successfully in the following order: NamespaceLifecycle,LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,NodeRestriction,TaintNodesByCondition,Priority,DefaultTolerationSeconds,DefaultStorageClass,StorageObjectInUseProtection,RuntimeClass,DefaultIngressClass,MutatingAdmissionWebhook.*
*I0909 15:46:37.161190       1 plugins.go:161] Loaded 11 validating admission controller(s) successfully in the following order: LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,PodSecurity,Priority,PersistentVolumeClaimResize,RuntimeClass,CertificateApproval,CertificateSigning,CertificateSubjectRestriction,ValidatingAdmissionWebhook,ResourceQuota.*
*Error: context deadline exceeded*

If we validate the status of etcd on both masters, it says the following on the main master:
*[root@TMT102 jenkinsqa]# systemctl status etcd
*● etcd.service - etcd*
*   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/etcd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)*
*   Active: active (running) since Fri 2024-09-06 08:41:51 -04; 3 days ago*
*     Docs: https://github.com/coreos*
* Main PID: 921 (etcd)*
*    Tasks: 10 (limit: 23184)*
*   Memory: 70.3M*
*   CGroup: /system.slice/etcd.service*
*           └─921 /usr/local/bin/etcd --name TMT102 --cert-file=/etc/etcd/kubernetes.pem --key-file=/etc/etcd/kubernetes-key.pem --peer-cert-file=/etc/e>*

*Sep 09 11:49:08 TMT102 etcd[921]: health check for peer 38b126bffa9e7ff7 could not connect: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid*
*Sep 09 11:49:08 TMT102 etcd[921]: rejected connection from "10.161.169.26:36578" (error "remote error: tls: bad certificate", ServerName "")*
*Sep 09 11:49:08 TMT102 etcd[921]: rejected connection from "10.161.169.26:36588" (error "remote error: tls: bad certificate", ServerName "")*
*Sep 09 11:49:08 TMT102 etcd[921]: rejected connection from "10.161.169.26:36590" (error "remote error: tls: bad certificate", ServerName "")*
*Sep 09 11:49:08 TMT102 etcd[921]: rejected connection from "10.161.169.26:36600" (error "remote error: tls: bad certificate", ServerName "")*
*Sep 09 11:49:08 TMT102 etcd[921]: rejected connection from "10.161.169.26:36616" (error "remote error: tls: bad certificate", ServerName "")*
*Sep 09 11:49:08 TMT102 etcd[921]: rejected connection from "10.161.169.26:36632" (error "remote error: tls: bad certificate", ServerName "")*
*Sep 09 11:49:08 TMT102 etcd[921]: rejected connection from "10.161.169.26:36644" (error "remote error: tls: bad certificate", ServerName "")*
*Sep 09 11:49:08 TMT102 etcd[921]: health check for peer 38b126bffa9e7ff7 could not connect: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid*
*Sep 09 11:49:08 TMT102 etcd[921]: rejected connection from "10.161.169.26:36648" (error "remote error: tls: bad certificate", ServerName "")*

If we validate the status of the kubelet, we fail to recognize the node:
root@TMT102 jenkinsqa]# systemctl status kubelet
● kubelet.service - kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/kubelet.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d
           └─10-kubeadm.conf
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2024-09-06 08:41:52 -04; 3 days ago
     Docs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/
 Main PID: 1055 (kubelet)
    Tasks: 17 (limit: 23184)
   Memory: 117.9M
   CGroup: /system.slice/kubelet.service
           └─1055 /usr/bin/kubelet --bootstrap-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf --config=/va>

Sep 09 11:50:02 TMT102 kubelet[1055]: E0909 11:50:02.966092    1055 kubelet.go:2407] "Error getting node" err="node \"tmt102\" not found"
Sep 09 11:50:03 TMT102 kubelet[1055]: E0909 11:50:03.066193    1055 kubelet.go:2407] "Error getting node" err="node \"tmt102\" not found"
Sep 09 11:50:03 TMT102 kubelet[1055]: E0909 11:50:03.167212    1055 kubelet.go:2407] "Error getting node" err="node \"tmt102\" not found"
Sep 09 11:50:03 TMT102 kubelet[1055]: E0909 11:50:03.267684    1055 kubelet.go:2407] "Error getting node" err="node \"tmt102\" not found"
Sep 09 11:50:03 TMT102 kubelet[1055]: E0909 11:50:03.368502    1055 kubelet.go:2407] "Error getting node" err="node \"tmt102\" not found"
Sep 09 11:50:03 TMT102 kubelet[1055]: E0909 11:50:03.468755    1055 kubelet.go:2407] "Error getting node" err="node \"tmt102\" not found"
Sep 09 11:50:03 TMT102 kubelet[1055]: E0909 11:50:03.569086    1055 kubelet.go:2407] "Error getting node" err="node \"tmt102\" not found"
Sep 09 11:50:03 TMT102 kubelet[1055]: E0909 11:50:03.670261    1055 kubelet.go:2407] "Error getting node" err="node \"tmt102\" not found"
Sep 09 11:50:03 TMT102 kubelet[1055]: E0909 11:50:03.771753    1055 kubelet.go:2407] "Error getting node" err="node \"tmt102\" not found"
Sep 09 11:50:03 TMT102 kubelet[1055]: E0909 11:50:03.872367    1055 kubelet.go:2407] "Error getting node" err="node \"tmt102\" not found"

With these errors we cannot connect to manage the Kubernetes cluster, what could be happening, it is an OnPremise Bare Metal installation

Did you have time to check my answer? It helped you to solve your problem? If not let me know,I am happy to assist you further.

Make sure that the certificates on both master nodes are correctly updated. You can do this by checking the certificates and keys used by the API server and etcd.
Since you are facing the issue after updating the certificates try restarting the control plane components to know whether they have picked up the new certificates correctly,
  systemctl restart kube-apiserver
  systemctl restart kube-controller-manager
  systemctl restart kube-scheduler

Ensure that etcd certificates(etcd-server.crt,etcd-server.key,etc) are updated on all the master nodes.Check the etcd configuration file (/etc/etcd/etcd.cofg) for the correct certificate path and make sure that etcd is started with the updated certificates. Also you can try restarting etcd,
systemctl restart etcd

Additionally you can go through this official GCP documentation for more information on this.
If you have already updated the certs or it has been updated automatically, you would have to restart the kube-apiserver on all master nodes.
Go to the masters and look for docker,
ps | grep -i kube-apiserver

Kill them with dockerkill the containers and wait for 10-15 seconds it should start working.
And regarding the error message “could not connect:x509:certificate has expired or is not yet valid” you can also look at this which will be very helpful to fix this issue.

Hi, I managed to solve the problem, the kubernetes.pem certificate was expired, it was located in the /etc/etcd folder and was not updated with the kubeamd renew certs all command, we had to update it manually. Thank you very much for your support.
